# Finding unique loops in the closed graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I finally managed to write a code to identify all the loops possible with the current configuration.  For example, for the image below, the following is the input to my program.

[image: Graph Problem]

```
network2=Pipes.NetworkManager(vertices=[1,2,3,4],
                 nodes=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,3),
                        (2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)])

network2.search_loop()
```

Now, I have hard-time in filtering the data from my output to find the unique loop.

This is the result:

```
starting search from 1
--------------------------------------------------------
the loop is complete [1, 2, 3, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 2, 4, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 2, 4, 3, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 3, 2, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 3, 2, 4, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 3, 4, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 3, 4, 2, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 4, 2, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 4, 2, 3, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 4, 3, 1]
the loop is complete [1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
--------------------------------------------------------
starting search from 2
--------------------------------------------------------
the loop is complete [2, 1, 3, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 1, 3, 4, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 1, 4, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 1, 4, 3, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 3, 1, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 3, 4, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 4, 1, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 4, 1, 3, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 4, 3, 1, 2]
the loop is complete [2, 4, 3, 2]
--------------------------------------------------------
starting search from 3
--------------------------------------------------------
the loop is complete [3, 1, 2, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 1, 4, 2, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 1, 4, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 2, 1, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 2, 1, 4, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 2, 4, 1, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 2, 4, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 4, 1, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 4, 2, 1, 3]
the loop is complete [3, 4, 2, 3]
--------------------------------------------------------
starting search from 4
--------------------------------------------------------
the loop is complete [4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 1, 2, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 1, 3, 2, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 1, 3, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 2, 1, 3, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 2, 1, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 2, 3, 1, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 2, 3, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 3, 1, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
the loop is complete [4, 3, 2, 4]
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I used the recursion( what else might be the better choice?) to solve the problem. Now after I obtain the result, I am finding it difficult to filter those results and to find the unique loops. My understanding of graph theory is limited( I just started reading about it). What might be the effective way of finding the unique loop from this identified loops?

Thanks for one answer which suggested that duplicate loop has the property of staying the same when reversed. For eg:

```
[1,2,3,1]
[1,3,2,1]
[2,3,1,2]
```

Iff it starts from the same vertex as first and second one in above case, reversing will indicate that those are same loops but in the third case, although it is the same loop as the first two, the situation is little tricky. Now the reverse should be done through the third vertex in that loop. This complication will increase when the number of vertex forming the loop increases. As such, any algorithms that effectively simplifies this problem? I see some recursive pattern here but still it is little complicated and would lie to know if somebody can suggest simple solutions.

Comment: I think while calculating loops starting from other vertices, you should discard the vertices that you have already considered as starting vertices for loops.

Comment: If you look closely in above case, ignoring the starting vertices when starting from the next vertex will let you lose some of the loops.

Comment: For example? Which loops will be lost?

Comment: Not to be picky, but you might want to rename **nodes** to **edges**

Comment: That's a good advice @ChristopherHarris. Yes, I stumbled into graph theory before I knew that my problem was related to graph and already programmed some portion of it and then realized, my use of terminology was wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I could not identify this in this graph problem when I did it to some other configuration, I lost some but regardless, that is not a point. I want to filter the results and get the unique graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a loop duplicate has the property that if you reverse the order of it you'll get the original loop.

To make your life easy, you can decide that you'll take the loop that has the lesser lexicographic index to your solution. Which means, if you found the loops `1->3->2->1` and `1->2->3->1` (which are equal by your definition), you'll take `1->2->3->1` to the solution.

Best way to proceed from this point would be to reverse each loop you found, if the reverse mode has a lower lexicographic index than the original, ignore the loop. otherwise add it to the solution.

You can check the lexicographic index by a very simple method, just create a number out of the order of vertices.

For example: translate `1->2->3->1` to `1231` and `1->3->2->1` to `1321`. `1231` is less than `1321`, thus `1->2->3->1` will be taken to the solution and `1->3->2->1` will be ignored.

**Edit:**

In order to eliminate duplicated loops that don't share the same starting (like in your example, `1->3->2->1` and `2->1->3->2`, you can ignore any loop for which the first vertex index is not the smallest index in the loop. here `2->1->3->2` can be ignored as the index `2` is not the smallest in the loop.

Comment: Please see my updated question with some complications that your answer might not address. I know what you are saying but that doesn't solve the whole problem

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this, after you can ensure you have the loop that is, is to create a set of frozensets.

```
>>> loop1 = [1,2,3,4,1]
>>> loop2 = [1,2,4,3,1]
>>> loop3 = [1,2,3,1]
>>> loops = [loop1,loop2,loop3]
>>> loops = set([frozenset(loop) for loop in loops])
>>> loops
set([frozenset([1, 2, 3, 4]), frozenset([1, 2, 3])])
```

This of course would force you to assume that the first item in the frozenset is the start and end vertex.

Comment: If you have a lot of loops this could be memory intensive, since a (frozen)set is a hash table and quite big in comparison to a list or tuple.  You could get the same result by sorting the list and converting it to a tuple before putting in the set, i.e. `loops = set(tuple(sorted(loop)) for loop in loops)`.