# Find all closed loops in a network

Tags: r, igraph

This question is basically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244965/finding-all-closed-loops-in-a-graph), however I'm interested in solutions in R.

Does anyone know an approach with `igraph` or other CRAN-based packages which would allow you to identify closed loops (for example, DGHD, BCDB, or BCEFDB, if the letters are nodes)?

Note that I have a relatively large network with ~ 700 edges and ~ 100 nodes, so it would be good if the solution is not computationally too expensive.

One more important piece of information is that my network is **directed**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are only interested in paths that do not go through any node twice except that the beginning equals the end.  With a little work, you can do this in igraph using `all_simple_paths`.  The key point to notice is that any closed loop without repeated nodes is a simple path from a vertex, v, to one of v's neighbors, followed by the single link from the neighbor back to v.  I will show how to get all simple closed loops like this starting and ending with a single node. You can simply loop through all of the nodes if you want all examples in the graph.

First, we need some example data.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(8,0.35)
plot(g)
```

[image: Example graph]

I will get the closed loops starting and ending at node 8, because that node shows the interesting issues.

```
V = 8
SP = all_simple_paths(g, from=V, to=neighbors(g, v=V))
```

We do not want to include paths that just go to a neighbor and directly back (like 8-2-8) so we eliminate the paths with just one link.

```
SP2 = SP[sapply(SP, function(p) length(p)> 2)]
```

Depending on what you want,  we might be done here, but I suspect that you do not want both a path and the same path in reverse, e.g. I think that you do not want both 8-2-5-8 and 8-5-2-8. We can get rid of these duplicates by insisting that the first neighbor (the second node in the path) has a smaller index than the last one.

```
SP3 = SP2[sapply(SP2, function(p) p[2] < p[length(p)])]
```

But we have also left off the return to the first node,  so we add the first node on to the end of each path.

```
SP4 = lapply(SP3, function(p) c(unclass(p), V))
SP4
[[1]]
[1] 8 2 5 8

[[2]]
[1] 8 2 5 4 8

[[3]]
[1] 8 2 5 7 3 4 8

[[4]]
[1] 8 4 3 7 5 8

[[5]]
[1] 8 4 5 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @G5W, this is quite neat. However, I've tried it out on my dataset (~ 700 edges, ~ 100 nodes), and it seems to be running forever just for 1 node. I'll let the topic open therefore for a while, to see if there are less computationally expensive solutions.

Comment: P.S. My network is also directed, which means that while this solution would give me an approximation, there would still need to be further filtering (my fault for not specifying this in the post).

Comment: You can specify directed paths in `all_simple_paths`